# Digital Communication System

Tags: digital-communications

1. How can we determine whether the receive filter is optimal or not in a digital receiver?
2. For a decision region, how can we choose a noise value zk?

Comment: There is so much information missing from this question that it's hard to know where to start. Please fill in details and let's see if we can re-open and answer it.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends upon the modulation scheme that is being used. You calculate the probability of a bit error using your receiver of choice, then based on the characteristics of the systems in use, you calculate or bound the best probability of error that you could possibly get, then compare the two answers. For linear modulation on the [additive-white-Gaussian-noise (AWGN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise) channel, the optimum receiver filter is one whose impulse response is [matched to the pulse shape used at the transmitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter).
2. It's not clear what you're asking. Noise values aren't typically something that you choose; nature does.